What does the partition_depth_histogram actually show?
partition_depth_histogram is some kind of metric that can be read about here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_clustering_information
The definition reads:

A histogram depicting the distribution of overlap depth for each
micro-partition in the table. The histogram contains buckets with
widths:
0 to 16 with increments of 1.

For buckets larger than 16, increments of twice the width of the previous bucket (e.g. 32, 64, 128, …).


This leaves many questions:

Why is it always 17 buckets? What if we have more or fewer micro-partitions than 17?
What is the relation between micro-partitions and buckets in the histogram?
What do the numbers in the histogram mean?

To facilitate discussion and explanation, here is an example histogram and other metrics:



SYSTEM$CLUSTERING_INFORMATION('TEST2', '(COL1, COL3)')




{


"cluster_by_keys" : "LINEAR(COL1, COL3)",


"total_partition_count" : 1156,


"total_constant_partition_count" : 0,


"average_overlaps" : 117.5484,


"average_depth" : 64.0701,


"partition_depth_histogram" : {


"00000" : 0,


"00001" : 0,


"00002" : 3,


"00003" : 3,


"00004" : 4,


"00005" : 6,


"00006" : 3,


"00007" : 5,


"00008" : 10,


"00009" : 5,


"00010" : 7,


"00011" : 6,


"00012" : 8,


"00013" : 8,


"00014" : 9,


"00015" : 8,


"00016" : 6,


"00032" : 98,


"00064" : 269,


"00128" : 698


},


"clustering_errors" : [ {


"timestamp" : "2023-04-03 17:50:42 +0000",


"error" : "(003325) Clustering service has been disabled.\n"


}


]


}




The partition_depth_histogram in Snowflake's SYSTEM$CLUSTERING_INFORMATION function can be a bit confusing. I tried to break down  your questions with examples:
1. Why is it always 17 buckets?
The number of buckets in the partition_depth_histogram is not always 17. It's actually a combination of two factors:
Fixed Buckets (0-16): The first 17 buckets (numbered from "00000" to "00016") represent a fixed range from 0 to 16 overlap depth with increments of 1. This provides detailed information about micro-partitions with very low overlap.
Dynamic Buckets (Larger than 16): For overlap depths exceeding 16, the buckets increase in size based on a doubling scheme. This means the next bucket would be "00032" (twice the size of the previous bucket) and so on. This approach efficiently represents the distribution of overlap depth for a wider range of values.
2. What is the relation between micro-partitions and buckets in the histogram?
The partition_depth_histogram doesn't directly map micro-partitions to specific buckets.  Instead, it shows the number of micro-partitions that fall within a certain overlap depth range.
Bucket Value: Each bucket represents a specific overlap depth range.
Value in the Bucket: The value associated with a bucket (e.g., 98 in "00032") indicates the number of micro-partitions in that specific overlap depth range.
3.What do the numbers in the histogram mean?
The numbers in the histogram represent the count of micro-partitions within a specific overlap depth range.
In your example:
There are 0 micro-partitions with an overlap depth of 0 ("00000").
There are 3 micro-partitions with an overlap depth between 2 and 3 ("00002").
There are 98 micro-partitions with an overlap depth between 32 and 64 ("00032").
There are 698 micro-partitions with an overlap depth exceeding 128 ("00128").

I don't think your note is very accurate.  What this actually means is that the table isn't very well clustered on the cluster key specified.  This could be because the clustering has just been set or (as the error shows) cluster service has been disabled.  This would result in poor performance, not good performance.

Thanks for highlighting, I have edited.
